# get the last time a user was logged in?

Tags: shell

How can I get the last time a user was logged in, and have the output be just the date?

If I do `sudo lastlog` I can see all of this information in the "latest" column, but for all users. I want to be able to do this for an individual user.

So for a user of "testuser", I would want to run a command to see what the "latest" column has for him, such as `Tue Jun 13 13:46:36 +0000 2017`

And I'm on CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611

Comment: [man lastlog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lastlog); tl:dr is -u for a specified user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

sudo lastlog -u testuser | awk '{print $4,$5,$8}' | awk '{if(NR>1)print}'